# How to validade a AWS Certificate with Hostinger domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cname, aws-certificate-manager

I'm getting trouble to validate my AWS Certificate Manager with a Hostinger domain using DNS validation. I've already followed the tips from [DNS Validation for GoDaddy domain with ACM](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=284781) that worked for GoDaddy. Also, I've checked all the problems listed at [Troubleshoot Certificate Request Problems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-requests.html#failed-other)
 but without success too. Does anyone have the same problem?

Thank you!

**Update 1:**

I'm trying to **Request a public certificate** using **DNS validation** as validation method.

**Update 2 (17/05/19):**

Steps I followed:

1. I created a request at 8:52 AM.
2. Checked at 9:56:

[image]

3. Added CNAME to DNS provider at 9:59 AM:

[image]

4. Checked status at 10:49 AM:

[image]

Comment: Are you attempting to import certificate under AWS Cert Manager? Have you looked at these: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate-prerequisites.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate-format.html

Comment: @Woodrow thank you for your reply. I updated my question. I'm not attempting to import a certificate but request one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was getting:

> Failure Reason CAA Error

The missing configuration was that Amazon wasn't configured as CAA DNS record, as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/setup-caa.html).

> You can optionally configure a Certification Authority Authorization (CAA) DNS record to specify that AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) is allowed to issue a certificate for your domain or subdomain. After it validates your domain, ACM checks for the presence of CAA records to make sure it can issue a certificate for you.

To achieve that, I've added this DNS record:

```
nome    Conteúdo                  prio
@       0 issue "amazon.com"      0
@       0 issuewild "amazon.com"  0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! this was super usefull!!